# Remove folder recursively but exclude named folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code help in deleting folder recursively. It deletes entire folder.

```
var deleteFolderRecursive = function(removePath) {
  if( fs.existsSync(removePath) ) {
    fs.readdirSync(removePath).forEach(function(file,index){
      var curPath = path.join(removePath, file);
      if(fs.lstatSync(curPath).isDirectory()) {
        deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
      } else { // delete file
        fs.unlinkSync(curPath);
      }
    });
    fs.rmdirSync(removePath);
  }
};
```

How could i extend it to delete folder recursively but excluding some folder by their folder name. Suppose that a folder with name `parentFolder` has child folder name `folderName1`, `folderName2`, `folderName3`. `folderName1` and `folderName2` and all its file will not be deleted if i declare in following way.

```
var deleteFolderRecursive = function (removePath, excludeDirArray) {
    // code here
}
deleteFolderRecursive(path, ['folderName1', 'folderName2']);
```

Comment: Do you want directories in the excluded list to be entirely ignored or also traversed to have file/directory within them also removed if not excluded?

Answer (score 1):

```
var deleteFolderRecursive = function(removePath, exclusive) {
  var shouldDelete = function(pathUrl) {
    if(exclusive && exclusive.length){
      return exclusive.indexOf(pathUrl) === -1;
    }
    return true;
  }

  if(fs.existsSync(removePath) && shouldDelete(removePath)) { // <-- use it here
    fs.readdirSync(removePath).forEach(function(file,index){
      var curPath = path.join(removePath, file);
      if(fs.lstatSync(curPath).isDirectory()) {
        deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
      } else { // delete file
        if(shouldDelete(file)) {   // <-- optionally use it here
          fs.unlinkSync(curPath);  // if you want also files to not be deleted
        }
      } 
    });
    fs.rmdirSync(removePath);
  }
};

deleteFolderRecursive(path, ['folderName1', 'folderName1', 'myFile.txt']); // <-- also file
```

Comment: Hi, I have follow this by using `deleteFolderRecursive(path, ['folderName1'])` but it stills result in entire folder to be deleted. It doesnt exclude folderName1. It seems to me that shouldDelete will return true as long as the second parameter is being defined

Comment: try this `deleteFolderRecursive('folderName1', ['folderName1'])` and confirm that it deletes folder, it shouldn't delete, if it does - something wrong

Comment: Hi it doesnt delete folder by using `deleteFolderRecursive('folderName1', ['folderName1'])` . My current folder hierarychy is in such a way: `www/parentFolder/folderName1`, so what i do is calling `deleteFolderRecursive('../../www/parentFolder', ['folderName1'])`. Not sure if i use it in wrong way but the entire parent folder got deleted.

Comment: don't use like this `../../www/parentFolder/folderName1`, you have to use `path.resolve` or something similar, or just pass folderName1 and tweak the function, because `exclusive.indexOf(pathUrl) === -1` will never return false. Because it's ['folderName1'].indexOf('../../www/parentFolder/folderName1') which is incorrect,

Comment: Oops I am trying to make this simpler. This is the actual path that i wrote in my program though but it still not working: `var path = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/android/assets/www/parentFolder');` So the entire function is `deleteFolderRecursive(path, ['folderName1'])`;

Comment: then you have to write `deleteFolderRecursive('../../platforms/android/assets/www/parentFolder/folderName1', ['../../platforms/android/assets/www/parentFolder/folderName1'])`, but you better tweak this function, anyway this is getting quite boring, just go ahead and play with it!

Comment: Just tried `deleteFolderRecursive(path, [path + '/folderName1']);` but it stills delete the entire parentFolder